# How to efficiently synchronize access to a directory inorder to maximize concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Imagine that we have a client/sever app. The client will send directories to the server and the server would store it.

The client protocol is as follows for communicating with the server.

1. Send the clientId. [say client1]
2. Send the metadata for the directory.
3. Send the directory. [/tmp/client1]

The server does the following thing in response.

1. Verifies the clientId.
2. Analyse the metadata for the client directory.
3. Store the file at [/tmp/server/client1].

Usually we want the server to be multithread so that it can service multiple clients at a time. For each client a new thread will be spawned to take care of it.

So here is part of the server code which reads the dir from the client.

```
public DirServer readDir() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    DirClient clientDir = (DirClient) objectInputStream.readObject();
    String serverDirPath = "/tmp/server"
        + "/" + clientId;

    List<FileServer> serverFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    DirServer dirServer = null;

    synchronized (lockObject) {
      FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(serverDirPath));
      Path pathToDir = Paths.get(serverDirPath);
      Files.createDirectories(pathToDir.getParent());

      for (int i = 0; i < clientDir.getNumberOfFiles(); i++) {
        serverFiles.add(readFile());
      }
      dirServer = new dirServer(clientDir.getFullPath(), serverDirPath, serverFiles);
    }

    return dirServer;
  }
```

So say we have two threads in the thread pool to serve the clients for now.

Case 1:

Thread 1: client1

Thread 2: client1

i.e two instances of client1 from different machines try to contact the server. For this case synchronized access to code block is desirable, because they access the same path /tmp/server/client1.

Case 2:

Thread 1: client1

Thread 2: client2

For this case it is far efficient to not have synchronized access to the code block. As both threads deal with different paths /tmp/server/client1 and /tmp/server/client2.

How should one achieve this conditional sync ? i.e sync only when you are accessing the same directory and not sync otherwise.

Note that doing synchronized(clientDir) won't work because this object is read over the network. So although two clientDir might be logically the same they are actually two different references.

You can assume that you can do clientDir.getClientId() to get the Id for a client.

Comment: Why? You're only carrying out operations on the file system. There's no need to synchronize those. If they both attempt to upload the same file, one of them will get an error, as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you you need to synchronize on "logical clientDir".
You may use `clientDir` as a `key` to get a dummy object from a hashmap, and synchronize on it.

Writing to hashmap should be synchronized, but not reading. And amount of writing can not exceed amount of "logical client dirs".

== EDIT ==
Reading **which returns an existing dummy object** is OK (since they will behave like finals), no need synchronization.
Reading which returns `null` will require a re-read and (possibly) write inside synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locking a global valiable as following(as you do)

```
synchronized (lockObject){}//whwere lockObj is global
```

lock a session(client) scope object which each session would have one, simply using a list.

```
class client_session{public long id;/*client stuffs/attribs*/
//don't forget to implement the equals
}
//---
Vector<client_session> sess=new Vector<client_sesion>();//vector or whatever
//---
//for any client request
client_session sx=null;
synchronized(sess){
int idx=sess.indexOf(long_id);
if(idx==-1){sess.add(sx=new client_session(long_id));}
else{sx=sess.elementsAt(idx);}
}
//---
//now lock the client/session
synchronized (sx/*instead of lockObject*/){/*lock only one session/client*/}
```

Now 10 different client would be maintained parallel, but two request from one client will be maintained serially.